# Is there any benefit using index or foreignKey in slick table schema?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Should i use indexes and foreignKey in slick schema table? Is there any benefits like performance or query planner?
We are using Flyway DB migration tool so we wont use this schema with `schema.create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys in slick schema table would help you in two cases

first is from [slick doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/schemas.html)

> ...foreign key can be used to navigate to the referenced data with a join. For this purpose, it behaves the same as a manually defined utility method for finding the joined data ...

And if you generate DB schema using slick (for example, in tests)

Answer (score -1):

Setting up indexes help you to fasten your searching(data retrieval), but slows down insertion. So you need to decide according to your requirement what you want. If there is more searching and data in DB is huge you should go for indexing.

Foreign keys, on the other hand, are used to maintain the relationship between different tables which are used for join in relational DB. Adding foreign keys will not have any impact on performance.

You can get more insight on indexing here -> [Indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index),
And for foreign key here -> [Foreign Key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: We are also using indexes and fk in postgresql side. I need answer about is should i use in my code specifically slick schema definition.

Comment: Adding indexes are not necessary if you already have them in the database. Adding foreign on the other hand will help you in writing join queries in slick. But, if you can add indexes also in the slick schema, that would help you and others in relating the table constraints more accurately(As they will have all the constraints at one place for a table and will not have to check DB for looking various constraints). Hope this should help.

Comment: FK do have imptact on performance. They need to be checked during insert, update and delete if they could be broken. It is possible (depending on schema) that most of execution time for those queries will be taken by FK checks.

Comment: Agree to that point, But in the context of the question, foreign keys will not have any impact on the performance, as they are already defined in the database schema. Defining fk in slick table schema will help in writing slick join queries.

Comment: This is not the answer to the original question. He is asking about  defining indexes and foreignKey in slick schema table. Not in the DB.